# Substitution for integral of type $\frac{1}{(ax^2 +b)\sqrt{px^2+q}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{dx}{(ax^2 +b)\sqrt{px^2+q}}$$
A  good substitution for this will be $x=\frac{1}{t}$
$$dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}$$
$$\int \frac{\frac{-1}{t^2}{dt}}{(\frac{a}{t^2} +b)\sqrt{\frac{p}{t^2}+q}}$$
$$\int \frac{-t dt }{(a +bt^2)\sqrt{p + qt^2}}$$
Then I have to go for one more substitution 
$$p+qt^2=z^2$$

I want to know  is there any other good substitution which can solve it in single substitution .

Comment: Have you tried $\mathrm{p+qx^{-2}=z^2}$?

Comment: @VishalGupta It will make the think cubic .

Comment: Whoops, I meant $\mathrm{q+px^{-2}=z^{2}}$ and factoring out the x terms from the square root and the other thing in the denominator gets rid of the cubic. I'm not sure about $\mathrm{b+ax^{2}} in terms of z though...

Answer (score 1):

If you let
$$
u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{px^2+q}}
$$
you will get
$$
\int\frac{1}{b-(bp-aq)u^2}\,du,
$$
which I think you can handle.